# stop elements wrap in div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Suppose I have 15 images, which I want to display in a div.
So, I add them dynamically using JQuery.

But the output is
[image]

The css for the above image is

```
.item
    {
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
        background-image: url('images/txt.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position-x: center;
    }
```

and css for div is :

```
#fileName
    {
            margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

so I tried the following css :

```
#fileName
        {
            margin-top: 10px;
            overflow-x : auto;
        }
```

then my o/p is :

[image]

I have also tried `overflow-wrap` css property. But still I cant solve my problem.

I want to have all the images in one line and if it does not fit the div then div should have a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this on the parent:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

and `display: inline-block;` instead of floats

Comment: If it will work with `float`, then perfect. If it won't, then replace `float` with `display: inline-block;`

Comment: with white-space: nowrap. Thanks Lorof.

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-block` will do it for you.

Comment: `display: inline-block` on the item suggested by Sanja and `white-space: nowrap` on the div suggested by Lorof gives me the answer.

Comment: Ya i see the comments. Great to know you problem is solved. :)